# return in function returning wrong value

Tags: javascript

I have written a function which will make total of a certain number and return it to me

Here is the function

```
function getTotal(val, total) {

    if (total.length > 1 || total == 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
            total = total + parseInt(val[i])
        }
    };

    if (('' + total).length > 1) {
        val = '' + total;
        total = 0;

        getTotal(val, total);
    };

    return total;
};

var finalTotal = getTotal('04151993', 0);
```

For example `val = '04151993'` according to my function it will run twice and at last it should return 5;

While debugging i can see the total is 5 but when return code executes it return value 0.

Any idea?

Comment: You're ignoring the return value of the "inner" `getTotal`. And what's the purpose of `var total ...; var val ...;` which are already available trough the parameters?

Comment: `val = '04151993'`, but what is `total`?

Comment: `total.length`? what do you pass total as?? `''`?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `total.toString`?

Comment: @user202729 total is 0. Updated.

Comment: @Andreas I was just trying some ways. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're not returning when calling  `getTotal` recursively. See:

```js
function getTotal(val, total) {
    if (total.length > 1 || total == 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
            total = total + parseInt(val[i])
        }
    };

    if (('' + total).length > 1) {
        val = '' + total;
        total = 0;

        return getTotal(val, total); // return here
    };

    return total;
};

console.log(getTotal('04151993', 0));
```